# How does data.title become undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Why is my output not rendering. There is an instance of the object that is passed into this component `({data})` and it has a property of title which is a string value. When I `console.log(data.title)`
the output is the string representation of that property. But on the other hand there is no visible render to the dom.

```
import React from "react";

/**
 * returns the component for the modal title
 * @param data
 * @returns {*}
 * @constructor
 */
export const HeaderTitle = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data && data.title); //data.title is truthy here   
                                       //data.title is falsy here
  return <h1 className="header__title">{data && data.title} </h1>;
};
```

[image]

reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { movies } from "./movies";

// combine reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
  movies,
});

export default reducers;
```

movies.js

```
import { initialState } from "../../_data/index";
const FETCH_DATA = "FETCH_DATA";
const FETCH_RESULTS = "FETCH_RESULTS";
export const movies = (
  state = {
    moviesinfo: [],
    results: initialState,
  },
  action
) => {
  // check action type
  if (action.type === FETCH_DATA) {
    state = { ...state, moviesinfo: action.payload };
  }
  if (action.type === FETCH_RESULTS) {
    state = { ...state, results: action.payload };
  }

  return state;
};

export default movies;
```

Comment: do you mind to share the reducer code as well?

Comment: Added the reducer code as well.

Comment: Could you also share some code indicating where this component is used?

Comment: From your log message, it looks like render gets called twice (the log looks like it does at least), once with undefined, and then immediately with a defined value ('Ad Astra'). Does it then not make it into the DOM when react renders?